How to mass request branches from git with individual file as comparison with a reasonable execution duration?
I am an intern task with identifying the branch where the file was last deployed using this git command: "git log -n 1 --merges --first-parent --oneline -- filename"
This helps me identify each file and their respective branch, however since I am dealing with over tens of thousands of files, this process is slow.
Issue: Unable to find a quick and accurate way to find branches for respective files without losing accuracy.
Tools used: Python, Bitbucket, Jira, Git
Desired results: Process a list of files (tens of thousands of files) and find their respective branch with a reasonable duration of execution
Things I tried:
I have tried using "git diff --name-only master..branch" after finding the branch to find which files are updated on that branch to speed up the process however this is not always accurate since some files are not listed there or are updated again later.
(Example: running the first git command locates the branch return branch A. Running the second command with Branch A returns all the files changed/updated on branch A. Results returned from Branch A does not contain the file used to identify branch A when running the first git command)
Is there another simpler way to get branches associated with individual files fast?

What is "the branch where the file was last deployed" supposed to mean? Are you looking for last commit involving that file? Are you looking for a (possibly already deleted) branch that was merged in that commit? Something like this q?

I am trying to find the latest change made to that file and which branch is that change located at. I do not think deleted branches are an issue as I do not think they delete branches (at least not yet)

...I have trouble imagining a workflow where this is at all relevant. What's the actual goal here? Why are you being asked to do this?

git log --first-parent --merges --oneline --name-status -m \
| awk '!/^[^ ]*\t/  { oneline=$0; next }
       !seen[$NF]++ { print $0"\t"oneline }
' FS=$'\t'

--merges says list only merges, -m says check diffs for merges (instead of bypassing them in favor of whatever commits first made the merged changes), the awk remembers commit lines and looks for the first occurrence of each tracked path appearing in a status line, and prints the responsible commit.

So -m is the parameters where it only shows the diff after merges?
sorry I am very new to git. I would also like to know what are the details behind too?

Ordinarily git log does not check merges for changes, because ordinarily you're looking for the commit that made those changes not the merges that just propagated them. -m says nono really I want to see the changes merges brought too.

Ohhhhh this makes a lot of sense now thanks. I have one last question, how do I use those parameters I see, are they just formats for the exported results? I tried entering it and it does not show anything

I'm sorry, I can't work out what you're asking. Show what you're looking at, copy the transcript into the question.

I get the first part until -m. the rest I do not know what they mean. :
git log --first-parent --merges --oneline --name-status -m 
| awk '!/^[^ ]*\t/  { oneline=$0; next }
!seen[$NF]++ { print $0"\t"oneline }
' FS=$'\t'
My issue is already solved thanks but I am just curious what the rest of the command means
Sorry for the late reply I didnt know stackoverflow does not refresh automatically

Google knows about git help, say git help log and look up the options for more details than I gave here. awk is a fundamental tool, say man awk or on GNU/anything info gawk will give more details, leave the command off to see what it's processing, the awk here does what it appears to do: remember the oneline commit header and print it next to every file whose name it just saw for the first time.

Ok Thanksssssss
